# Passing More then One Parameter to [sp_execute_external_script] for Executing R code

Tags: sql, r, stored-procedures, sp-executesql, rtvs

Here is the scenario where i am trying to pass three parameter namely `empid2` and  `Name1` & `DOB1`. i am unable to pass the parameter and get the resultant data frame at the `OutPutDataset`. **Observed** : with One Parameter passing i am getting the result but with more then one parameter i am unable to get the Output Data Frame.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGetAllEmployees] 
@empid2 int,
@Name1 Varchar(50)
--@DOB1 Date   
as    
Begin    
Declare @empid int
Declare @NewName varchar(50)

EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
 @language = N'R'
,@script = N'df <- as.data.frame(InputDataSet);df[,1] <- df[,1]+1;OutputDataSet <-df'
,@input_data_1 = N'select * from tblEmployee where EmployeeId=@empid AND Name=@NewName'
,@params = N'@empid Int OUTPUT'
,@empid = @empid2
,@NewName =@Name1
--,@NewDOB=@DOB1
WITH RESULT SETS (([Col1] Int, [Col2] varchar(50), [Col3] varchar(50), Col4 varchar(50),Col5 varchar(50)));

End

-- EXEC dbo.spGetAllEmployees @empid2 ='1', @Name1='Nabi';
```

With Above Parameter `empid2` and  `Name1` & `DOB1` from given Data Frame/Data Table we are trying to subset the Table .
[image: Sub setting the Table with 3 Parameter and process through RScript and data in OutputDataset]

Comment: Have defined @NewName before using it in select query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Write **Output** Syntax `@Params` in the query.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGetAllEmployees] 
        @empid2 int,
        @Name1 Varchar(50),
        @DOB1 Date   
    as    
    Begin    
    Declare @empid int
    Declare @NewName varchar(50)
    Declare @NewDOB Varchar(50)

        EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
         @language = N'R'
        ,@script = N'df <- as.data.frame(InputDataSet);df[,1] <- df[,1]+1;OutputDataSet <-df'
        ,@input_data_1 = N'select * from tblEmployee where EmployeeId=@empid AND Name=@NewName AND DOB=@NewDOB'
        ,@params = N'@empid Int OUTPUT,@NewName varchar(50) OUTPUT,@NewDOB Varchar(50) OUTPUT'
        ,@empid = @empid2
        ,@NewName =@Name1
        ,@NewDOB=@DOB1
        WITH RESULT SETS (([Col1] Int, [Col2] varchar(50), [Col3] varchar(50), Col4 varchar(50),Col5 varchar(50),Col6 varchar(50)));

    End

    -- EXEC dbo.spGetAllEmployees @empid2 ='1', @Name1='Nabi',@DOB1='2017-04-01';
```